# Error when serializing byte[]

Tags: breeze

In our backing database, we have a Data field that is of type varbinary(max). Using Breeze we are able to save data in this field, however, when we want to call it back down we are getting errors. In our generated models, the field gets mapped to a byte[]. But when Breeze tries to serialize that into a string it throws up errors.

```
$id: "1",
$type: "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
Message: "An error has occurred.",
ExceptionMessage: "The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Byte[]' type is not valid.",
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException",
StackTrace: " at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32 ordinal) at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I will try to look at it later today.

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to reproduce this.

Breeze is able to take a server side byte[] and convert it to a string on the client.  You can see an example of this in the breeze 'DocCode' samples whenever an Employee entity is returned.  The Employee type has a Photo property that has a server side datatype of 'byte[]' which is returned to the breeze client as a 'string'.

What I think you are running into is a server side materialization issue where you are trying to materialize a binary blob on the database into a string property.  This would occur if your model property was typed as a 'String' instead of as a 'byte[]'.

Hope this helps.